# How to create sitemap with the following structure (example.com/sitemap.xml) in Joomla

Tags: joomla, sitemap

I am using JSitemap PRO extension, but I can not create simple sitemap like: example.com/sitemap.xml
The URLs are getting dynamic parameters like ?view=xml id=1 format=xml.

SEF is in place.

Thanks

I tried to find a configuration, with no success.

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Joomlashack OSMap instead, it's free, Joomla 3/4 compatible.
https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/osmap/

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: No affiliation, apart from being a long time Joomla user myself, I use and always recommend this extension, because it will give OP what they need and I trust the vendor.